# RestSharp Post Json Object

Tags: c#, json, restsharp

I am trying to Post a simple Json object using RestSharp to add a new product. I'm getting an error response from the server
"{"status":400,"error":"There was a problem in the JSON you submitted: unexpected character (after ) at line 1, column 2 [parse.c:724] in '{'product':{'name':'Product name','opt1':'Colour'}}"}"

My code:

```
////
var json = "{\'product\':{\'name\':\'Product name\',\'opt1\':\'Colour\'}}";

IRestClient restClient = new RestClient();
IRestRequest request = new RestRequest()
{
    Resource = "https://api.targetsite.com/products/"
};

request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
request.AddHeader("Accept", "application/xml");
request.AddHeader("authorization", "Bearer " + token);
request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;
request.AddJsonBody(json);

IRestResponse response = restClient.Post(request);
////
```

I managed to achive the result I wanted using a curl statment but I would like to do it using RestSharp.

Curl statment -

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-type: application/json" -H "Authorization: Bearer <ACCESS_TOKEN>"
https://api.targetsite.com/products/ -d '{"product":{"name":"Product name","opt1":"Colour"}}'
```

This HttpClient call also works fine

```
   using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
{
    using (var request = new HttpRequestMessage(new HttpMethod("POST"), "https://api.targetsite.com/products/"))
    {
        request.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("Authorization", "Bearer <ACCESS_TOKEN>"); 

        request.Content = new StringContent("{\"product\":{\"name\":\"Product name\",\"opt1\":\"Colour\"}}");
        request.Content.Headers.ContentType = MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse("application/json"); 

        var response = await httpClient.SendAsync(request);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like a limitation on the API you are calling.

When you send the json with curl, you're using different delimiters (**"** instead of **'**).

My guess is that the API you're calling doesn't properly deserialize the JSON when **'** is used.

What you can try is replacing the escaped ' with " or replace this line in your code : `request.AddJsonBody(json)`
with
**`request.AddJsonBody(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json))`** provided that you have installed the newtonsoft package.

Comment: Thanks for reply but that also didn't work. Now I got this error "{\"type\":\"Bad Request\",\"message\":\"Required parameter missing: product\"}".